# What is the right way to export a jar using maven for a library project?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jar, dependency-management

I have a library project which is built in maven. It has its dependencies. I need to export this project as a jar (Not a runnable jar). Should I include the dependencies along with my jar or should I not? Because when I exported the dependencies with my jar, there were conflicts when the same jars of different versions were used for projects that added this project as a dependency. But if I don't export with the dependencies, at run time this library project throws NoClassDefFound errors for its dependencies. So what is the right way to do this? If I don't export the dependencies with my jar, is there a way that the project using this library project could download those jars for the library project? If that is how I would do it, then wouldn't it mean that the project using this project must be using maven too? It won't be a good practice as whoever uses this library should be able to use whatever the build tools they want. I am pretty new to maven. Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is largely to taste, some open source projects do both, providing with for and without so that it is easier to use in larger projects.

If you are using Maven for your other projects you can, when you declare a dependency on this library tell maven to exclude some of its component jars.

Comment: When I exclude those jars, it adds maven as a dependency to my library. So the person using my library and creating an app is also bound to use maven. Is it a good practice to do it that way?

Comment: If you are developing a library for use by others outside your company/unit, you should have two versions, one with dependencies and one without, and list the dependencies the one without requires.  I am not sure why it should add maven as a dependency I don't recall seeing that in any of our libraries.

Comment: We tend to use shade to bundle up our library jars with their dependencies, we used to use one jar before that.

Comment: So if I give it without dependencies, how will I download them in my new project and give it at run time to those places needed in library project? And if I give it with the dependencies, its conflicting with the libraries used in the project which uses this library project. Did you come across any such issues?

Comment: If you have it without dependencies you have to add the dependencies to the projects pom, if you are using it with dependencies and they clash, you need to tell the projects pom to exclude the jars from inside the dependency. With in the ```<dependency></dependency>```tag for a given library you can added ```<exclude></exclude>``` tags